# How do researchers actually code novel architectures and layers?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, time-series, research

Disclaimer: I am almost a complete novice when it comes to tensorflow, keras, coding in general, and neural networks/data science.

While reading papers on novel architectures for neural nets, I see diagrams and such describing their ideas, and then they present their results, with no code shown. While learning to apply neural nets, I just load in the data, build a model by stacking layers like LSTM, Dense, etc, and training it. In other words I can't see how to do anything that isn't straight out of the box.

What tools, libraries, etc, do researchers use to implement these architectures when the layers aren't as simple as `model.add(Dense(1))`

For example, how might we implement the SeqMO algorithm described in this paper?
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.05357.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, I don't know how are they implementing these complex layers, but in Keras/TensorFlow you can define your own layers by inheriting from `tf.keras.layers.Layer`. For example, you could define a custom dense layer as (example from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers))

```py
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_outputs):
    super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs
  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
                                  shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
                                         self.num_outputs])
  def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)
```

If you're interested in this topic I recommend you [paperswithcode.com](https://paperswithcode.com/), where you can find a lot of code implementations of research papers. Hope it helps :)

---

EDIT:

Apparently, for your particular example the code is available [here](https://github.com/igfox/multi-output-glucose-forecasting), but they're using PyTorch, not Keras.